# IDA - execute commands in WinDbg console from python script

Tags: python, scripting, console, windbg, ida

I have a python script to run in IDA that generates commands for WinDbg. I also open the memory dump (via the windmp64.dll loader), where the WinDbg console is already available:

[image: available consoles]

I want to execute commands in WinDbg console from python script. If I'm right, I need something like `ida_expr.exec_idc_script()` but for WinDbg.

Comment: Have a look at [tag:pykd]

Comment: @ThomasWeller thanks, but my python scripts need access to the IDA environment (IDAPython).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ida_dbg.send_dbg_command()](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idapython_docs/ida_dbg.html#ida_dbg.send_dbg_command) is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).